# ArquillianResteasyResource caused initializationError - Method should have no parameters

Tags: java, junit, jboss-arquillian

I have simple JUnit test running with Arquillian, but when I want to use ArquillianResteasyResource(...) annotation, the test ends with "should have no parameters"

```
@Test
@InSequence
public void testSome(@ArquillianResteasyResource(RES_BASE_URI) SomeClass klazz) {
 // asserts using klazz
}
```

I have checked right imports, I have checked pom.xml dependencies. I didn't come up with anything.

So just wonder if anybody had same kind of issue?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Versions are:

- Junit: 4.11,
- Arquillian: 1.1.11.Final,
- Arquillia-Rest-Extension: 1.0.0.Alpha4.